# What is recommended size or ram for ubuntu 64bit virtualbox host?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, 64-bit, ram

I want to use ubuntu 14.04 64bit as a host to run virtual box. Some places say that the minimum ram requirement for ubuntu is 512mb where as on the downloads section it says that 64bit is only for computers with more than 2gb of ram. So I wanted to know what you think the ideal amount of ram I should give to ubuntu (as the host OS)? The OS which I'm running in virtualbox needs as much RAM as possible and I've only got 3.9gb of the stuff, so what do you recommend? I want the virtual machine to run as well as possible, and there will be no other program's running on ubuntu while I'm running the virtual machine.

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend 2GB, more apps running more RAM will eat, only compiz eat 357MB, firefox it's another RAM eater, so just run what you need

Answer (score 1):

I am fortunate enough to have 32 GB of the stuff, so I give it up to 10 or (once) 18, but my host is permanently using 10GB because I use both.

I would advise you go for 1500MB, as that should run reasonably well. You might find it runs smoother (even in the VB) if you use an alternative Desktop Environment (DE) such as XFCE or similar. I sometimes switch to that for RAM heavy stuff - even with 32GB.

The minimum is 512MB, but it honestly is not a pleasant experience with any less than 1GB, unless you use an alternative DE.

Comment: I want the virtual machine to have as much as possible. Ubuntu (the host) will be doing nothing but run virtualbox.

Comment: Also, I've been doing a bit more research and maybe if I'm trying to maximise the amount or ram I have available , would using lubuntu be better? If so, how would you recommend I split the RAM?

Comment: Yeah, lubuntu might be better, or xubuntu. Then i would suggest 1 GB.